# Trying to Load Ubuntu on 2007 MacMini

Tags: usb

Found an old 2007 MacMini that I'd like to load Ubuntu on.  Had some old memory, so upgraded to 4Gb. Could not get Ubuntu ISO on USB to be recognized (Don't know if USB 3.0 vs 2.0 comes into play here?).  Dug out an old DVD and loaded ISO, and it errors to a screen to select the CD-ROM drive that's stuck.  The internal hdd (80Gb) had MacOS 10.5.8 on it and would boot, but I can't even go to websites as the security profiles are so dated that no site will allow connection.

I'm throwing spaghetti at the wall trying all the tricks I can think of.  I tried using another machine and a hdd dock, take an old 2.5 hdd 250Gb and install Ubuntu 22.04 on it, but the grub records (which are always confusing to me) undoubtedly is hardware tied to the laptop I'm loading from and will not boot on the MacMini.

Hmmm, so now I format the 250Gb drive, partition it, restore a copy of the original 80Gb to a partition, install unbuntu iso on a 5Gb partition using balena etcher, and go ahead and put MacOS Extractor and Yosemite copied over to the 250Gb partition.  It's cc'ing now slowly 10Mb/s, but will try that.

Any other ideas? Or does anyone see something that I'm doing wrong? I am trying to get to a place that I can load OBS in Linux, and use it as a cheap video server for an rtsp camera feed into a website.

Comment: Some old links. Old Mac  Late 2006 iMac (iMac6,1) 18.04 with patched nVidia 304
https://adufray.com/blog/2018/06/02/nvidia-304-127-on-bionic
Mac 2007 delete gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420243

[SOLVED] Video performance of Ubuntu 16.04 on 2007 Mac Mini 2,1 (Intel Integrated 945GM/GMS)
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349732
Ubuntu 15.04 on Mac Mini 2,1 with EFI boot (2007 Intel)
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2287767